# Session is null when accessed via Ajax in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-variables

I have the following code in my application. The Constants.SESSION_USER is a string value.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public Account UserAccount
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session[Constants.SESSION_USER] is User)
            {
                return Session[Constants.SESSION_USER] as User;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[Constants.SESSION_USER]     = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Following is where I set the user to the `Session`

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Login(LoginViewModel loginView)
    {
        User loggedInAccount = null;    
        // some logic to validate the user

        // if no validation issues
        User loggedAccount = new User(loginView.ID);
        //set the logged account into the session
        this.UserAccount = loggedAccount;
    }
}
```

In the following code I am accessing the user session I previously set in the `AccountController`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetSession()
{
   User loggedInAccount = null;

   if (this.UserAccount != null) // this.UserAccount is null
   {
      //get the user from the session
      loggedInAccount = this.UserAccount;         
   }
}
```

When this `GetSession()` method is called via an ajax request, `this.UserAccount` is `null`.

I'm bit confused as sometimes this works and sometimes not. What's the problem here?

Comment: Your AJAX request doesn't send the session cookie. Don't reinvent authentication if you don't want security issues.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  session cookie is automatically send in the ajax request, isnt it ?.

Comment: Not if it's an HttpOnly cookie. We really can't say anyhting about this as it's all custom built.

Comment: @CodeCaster: ASP.NET session cookie is a HttpOnly cookie. I am calling this GetSesssion() method using ajax request in angularjs. The ajax request doesn't have the session cookie. Do I have to attach it,  Would you help me to solve this issue ?.

Comment: Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Seems to be this issue caused by the browser. Some settings in the browsers may have caused the session null (ASP.NET SessionId was not set in the browser). When I used a different browser it worked. Seems there is no code issue as well.